# Each digit of $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ equals $a$

Tags: number-theory

> For which digits $a$ does there exist an integer $n \geq 4$ such that each digit of $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ equals $a$?

I was first thinking of looking at $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \pmod{100}$, but it doesn't look like it has a small period so it may be hard to arrive at a conclusion. Is there an easier way to solve this question?

Comment: Simple examples?

Comment: Try $n = 10,11,36$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael We have to present a proof and not just give several examples.

Comment: Essentially you've to solve $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=a\frac{10^{m+1}-1}{9}$

Comment: @Winther Sorry, I meant $9n^2+9n = 2 \cdot 10^{m+1}-2$. How do I prove this has no solutions? Also, $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} = 444 \cdots 4$ and not $n$.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A045914

Comment: @Winther How do I prove that $9n^2+9n = 2 \cdot 10^{m+1}-2$ has no positive integer solutions?

Comment: In your comment to Winther and your other question, you lost a factor $a$.  It should be $9n^2+9n+2=2a\cdot 10^{m+1}$  The $n \ge 4$ is to make the triangular number have more than one digit.

Comment: @RossMillikan I am just taking the case of $a = 1$ for now.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $n(n+1)/2 = z$  has an integer solution iff $1+8z$ is a square.
So the question is whether $1 + \dfrac{8 a}{9} (10^k-1)$ can be a square, or equivalently whether $9 - 8 a + 8 a \cdot 10^k$ can be a square.
You can rule out $a = 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9$ this way because $9-8a$ is not a square $\mod (8 a \cdot 10^k)$ for $k=1$ or $2$.
That leaves $a=1$.

EDIT: For $a = 1$, you want $1 + 8 \cdot 10^k$ to be a square with $k \ge 2$.  Suppose it is $x^2$.  Since $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 5^k$, we may assume  $x \equiv 1 \mod 5^k$.
So let $x = 1 + 5^k y$.  Then we have $1 + 2 y \cdot 5^k + y^2 \cdot 5^{2k} = 1 + 8 \cdot 10^k$, or $2 y + y^2 \cdot 5^k = 2^{k+3}$.  In particular, $y \mid 2^{k+3}$, so $y$ is a power of $2$.  If $y = 2^j$, the equation becomes
$2^{j+1} + 2^{2j} \cdot 5^k = 2^{k+3}$.  Considering factors of $2$, two of $j+1, 2j, k+3$ must be equal.  But it's easy to rule out all these possibilities.

See also [OEIS sequence A045914](https://oeis.org/A045914).

EDIT: It's also interesting to consider other bases than $10$.  Here there are some infinite families of solutions, as well as some (such as $52 \dfrac{98^4-1}{98-1} = \dfrac{9944 \cdot 9945}{2}$ or $105 \dfrac{159^6-1}{159-1} = \dfrac{4634175 \cdot 4634176}{2}$) for which I don't see an obvious pattern.

In base $8j+1$, where $j$ is an integer, $j \dfrac{(8j+1)^{2k}-1}{8j+1-1} = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ where $n = \dfrac{(8j+1)^k-1}2$.

Comment: @RobertIsreal How do I prove that $9n^2+9n = 2 \cdot 10^{m+1}-2$ has no positive integer solutions?

Comment: I think I have a cleaner proof to rule out the $a=1$ case.  I've posted it as an answer.

Comment: @BarryCipra I think you want to show there are no $k$ values for a particular $a$ value.

Comment: @user19405892, that's what I did, for the particular value $a=1$.

Comment: @BarryCipra How can he eliminate $a=2,3,4,5,7,8,9$ by showing that a $9-8a \pmod{8a \cdot 10^k}$ is not a square for $k =1$ or $k=2$?

Comment: @user19405892, ask Robert, not me!

Comment: For example, for $a = 2$, $9 - 8 \cdot 2 = -7$ is not a square mod $5$ (i.e. not congruent to $0, 1$ or $4$ mod $5$), and therefore not a square mod $16 \cdot 10^k$ for any $k \ge 1$.  For $a=3$, $9 - 8 \cdot 3 = -15$ is not a square mod $25$, and therefore not a square mod $24 \cdot 10^k$ for any $k \ge 2$.

Comment: I am confused. If $a=2,3,4,7,8,9$ can be ruled out, what does "That leaves a=1" mean ? What about $a=5$ or $a=6$ ?

Comment: @Peter We know that $a=5$ and $a=6$ do appear, namely for (exhaustive) example when $n=10, 11, 36$ (cf. Robert's first comment to the question)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Robert Israel's answer, here is an alternative proof that $a=1$ cannot occur as the sole digit of a multi-digit triangular number.

If it did, then

$${n(n+1)\over2}={10^k-1\over9}$$

which can be rewritten as

$$(3n+1)(3n+2)=2\cdot10^k=2^{k+1}\cdot5^k$$

On the left hand side we have a product of two consecutive numbers, which are necessarily relatively prime.  Thus one must be the $2^{k+1}$ and the other the $5^k$.  It's easy to see that $2^{k+1}$ and $5^k$ differ by $1$ only for $k=0$ and $k=1$, neither of which gives a multi-digit triangular number.

Comment: OP asked the question with $a=1$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820271/prove-that-9n29n2-2-cdot-10m1-has-no-positive-integer-solutions) where I gave the same answer at just about the same time.  Great minds think alike.

Comment: @RossMillikan, it's nice to be in such good company!

Answer (score -2):

Use induction to show that $\sum_{i=0}^n i = \frac {n(n+1)}{2} $

Then the number with digit $a$, $aaa...a = \sum_{i=0}^n i$ for some $n $

These are the triangular numbers

Now to start the problem we can look at lists of Triangular numbers to see that both 55 and 66 are candidates.

Bellew and Weger showed that 666 is the largest such number.

Then the complete list of repdigit triangular numbers is 55, 66, and 666.

Comment: Does anyone have access to "The Magic Numbers of Dr Matrix", which is what the linked page refers to for a proof that $666$ is the largest triangular number with repeated digits?

Comment: This Answer would be improved by incorporating the explanation of the linked material given by @MartinKochanski in the above Comment.  As presently phrased it is unclear what specific fact or proposition the link is being cited to support (although Martin's Comment clarifies this).

Comment: You probably mean Benne de Weger (who proved such things in his thesis -- the equations are examples of what are called Ramanujan-Nagell equations ). Benne was probably a teenager in 1975 (his thesis was published in 1989).

Comment: @MartinKochanski et al., the Martin Gardner reference is not the pertinent one.  See Will Jagy's comments at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497931/find-the-five-smallest-positive-integer-w for more info on Bellew-Weger.