# Prove that $9n^2+9n+2=2\cdot 10^{m+1}$ has no positive integer solutions

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that $9n^2+9n+2=2\cdot 10^{m+1}$ has no positive integer solutions $m,n$ with $n \geq 4$.

I tried taking a certain modulus to show a contradiction but mod $10$ and mod $25$ both don't work.

Comment: Mod 2 and mod 9?

Comment: @MrYouMath I don't think either of those would help. Mod 2 both sides are $0$ (as $n^2\equiv n \pmod 2$), and mod 9 both sides are $2$.

Comment: Doesn't this simplify to: n (n+1)=2x1111.....111 (m ones)?  Can we show that this is an impossible decimal expansion?

Answer (score 1):

Factor it as $(3n+1)(3n+2)=2\cdot 10^{m+1}$  The two factors on the left have GCD of $1$, so one of them must be $2^{m+2}$ and the other must be $5^{m+1}$, but we know the only perfect powers that differ by $1$ are $3^2, 2^3$

Comment: Is it hard to prove that last fact?

Comment: It is known as [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), also called Mihăilescu's theorem as he proved it in 2002.  It doesn't sound easy.

Comment: What about $9n^2+9n=6\cdot 10^{m+1}-6$?

Comment: You don't need anything as fancy as Catalan, which concerns *arbitrary* powers.  Note that $5^{m+1}\gt4^{m+1}=2^{2m+2}=2^m\cdot2^{m+2}$, so $5^{m+1}-2^{m+2}\gt(2^m-1)2^{m+2}\gt1$ as soon as $m\gt0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra How would we prove $9n^2+9n = 6 \cdot 10^{m+1}-6$ has no positive integer solutions?

Comment: @Puzzled417, that's one of the cases (specifically $a=3$) Robert Israel ruled out in the first part of his answer at your other question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820126/each-digit-of-dfracnn12-equals-a

Comment: @BarryCipra Is there a way to prove it similar to like you did for this question?

Comment: @Puzzled417, if there is I don't see it.